# PowerShell GUI observer several socket-connections

Tags: sockets, powershell, user-interface

I have found lots of examples that are all very long - but I think it can be done in a lot shorter way.

I nee a GUI that displays and enables several options of the socket connections I need to adimn.

In the beginning I think I have:

```
    # Load external assemblies
    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
            $OnLoadForm_StateCorrection = {
                $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
            }

    $myGUI   = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $myGUI.Text = "Socket-Traffic"
    $myGUI.Name = "myGUI"
    $myGUI.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $myGUI.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,0,255) 
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 332
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 264
    $myGUI.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
```

Now I have the list of Hashes containing all relevant information of the variables and the connections. The groupe just has to be able to access their hash:

```
  $Sockets = $HASH1,$HASH2,$HASH3,$HASH4 # all hasches have a [string] ID: $HASH1.ID = $port
  $n = 0 # do I need that?
  foreach ($h in $Sockets) { 
     makeTab $myGUI $h $n
     $n++
  }
```

the function that I have in mind should start like that:

```
  function makeTab {
     param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
          [PSObject] $gui,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
          [PSObject] $hashTable, # with all info to connect and vars. 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
          [int] $noTab 
     )
     ... ??
  }
```

Each Socket-Tab has to have these internal groupes:

all function calls behind a buttonclick like:
$x_OnClick = { Write-host "Button clicked, do..." }

```
  1) Send-a-Line Groupe 
     a) Line to enter test meant to sent.
     b) Button to send  # no 'cancle'
  2) Login-Groupe: 
     a) status: Login=Green.ico, Connected=Orange.ico, nothing=red.ico
     b) Button: Login (connect & login)
     c) Button: Logout (Logout & disconnect)
  3) Logging-Groupe:
     a) last 2 Lines been sent
     b) last 2 line received
  4) Status Groupe
     a) text lines with var. info. about the connection
     b) text lines with var. info. about the connection
     ...
  Global - Finally
     a) Button to Exit the script with logout & disconnect all socket connections...
```

May s.o. can draft an example? After that I can determine the size and the place of the various and the buttons within a group.
Thank you very much in advance!
Gooly

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use PowerSHell 3.0 or higher, you can use WPF, where forms are just XML-like text. You can create an XML form in visual designer, like Visual Studio Express.
Like this: [TreeView Example](http://blog.coretech.dk/kaj/powershell-wpf-treeview-example/)